# Bind editable kendo grid items when click save button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, binding, kendo-grid

I have the following model

```
  public class CreateUserModel : DetailLayoutModel
{        
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public List<UserSettingModel> Settings { get; set; }
}

 public class UserSettingModel : BaseModel
{           
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public int MaxPercentage { get; set; }
    public int MaxValue { get; set; }
    public int MinPercentage { get; set; }
    public int MinValue { get; set; }

}
```

I have use for user settings editable kendo grid like the following:
[image]

the problem that when i press to create list the user setting list is null!
I want method to bind the kendo grid when I click save button.

I use Bind["models"] but not work
in my case I want to bind user setting list that exist in user model.

**Edit 1:**

the kendo grid in view , 
note: the kendo grid is filled when open. its bind the user settings to grid
My problem is :
1- when user fill values in grid and sort it or paginate the values is reset
2- when user click to submit button the the settings list not filled when received to action create , only the user name and email filled

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<UserSettingModel>(Model.Settings).Name("settings")
            .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
            .Pageable(a => a.ButtonCount(5).Numeric(false).Input(true))
            .Scrollable(a => a.Enabled(true))
            .Sortable(a => a.SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))
            .Selectable(a => a.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
            .Filterable(a => a.Extra(true))
            .Editable(x=>x.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))               
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax()
            .PageSize(5)
            .ServerOperation(false)
            .Read(read => read.Action("GetSettings", "User"))
             .Model(model =>
             {
                 model.Id(o => o.Id);
                 model.Field(p => p.Name).Editable(false);
             }))
    .BindTo(Model.Settings)
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Title(GlobalResources.Name);
        columns.Bound(p => p.MinValue);
        columns.Bound(p => p.MinPercentage);
        columns.Bound(p => p.MaxValue);
        columns.Bound(p => p.MaxPercentage);

    })))
```

Comment: have you tried setting the list property to a default value something like:  `model.settings = new List<UserSettingModel>()'

Comment: Yes ..but it not work

Comment: well I need more info in how this is being created and loaded then I should be able to help. Do you have a demo you show with this working in either a dojo or jsfiddle?

Comment: You have to add the data source transport read to your grid. I think the binding you re referring to is the initial binding. If you do not wire up a data source read method then how do you fetch the updated data?

Comment: @David i edit my question ,,, please look to edit 1

Comment: @Irb no intial binding work i mean the bind grid when post action occure